# Gorenstein ring VS. Gorenstein singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay, gorenstein

A normal variety is said to have Gorenstein singularity iff its canonical divisor is a Cartier divisor (one can always define the canonical divisor on a normal variety and it can be proved to be a Weil divisor).

What is the relation between Gorenstein singularity and Gorenstein ring? More precisely, is it true that a normal variety has Gorenstein singularity iff the local ring of its structure sheaf at any point is Gorenstein?

One can assume the normal variety is moreover Cohen-Macaulay if that helps.

Comment: Your definition of a Gorenstein singulairty does not require a local ring to be Cohen-Macaulay, but usually a Gorenstein local ring means the ring is Cohen-Macaulay and isomorphic to a canonical module. I believe that what you mentioned is called 1-Gorenstein.

Comment: Okay, let me assume that the variety is Cohen-Macaulay as well.